# Hard/blur shade lines around newly added faces

Tags: mesh, shaders, blur

[image: I was moddeling an ear when i decided to remove it. I deleted all the faces and some additional vertices and then filled the remaining space again now it shows these weird "hard lines"]

Im very much a beginner so the things ive tried are:

1. Pushing individual vertices deeper into the head this resulted in a decrease but not a fix:
   [image: after pushing vertices deeper into head.]
2. Ive tried to use "Smooth Vertices" but this didnt help.
3. Reapplied subvision modifier but outcome didnt change.

Has anyone had this before and knows how to solve it or why this happens?
Added a picture of my mesh without subdiv modif visible in viewport.

[image: Picture of my mesh without showing subdivision modif..]

Comment: have you checked for inner faces, overlapping vertices, flipped normals?

Comment: I didnt check for inner faces and flipped normals. I was however able to fix this. 
What i had done before was greate new vertices by extruding a vertices then linking them again to make the inner square then using F to fill. Somehow after making this post i really dont know how it showed me that there was a vertex in the center of the square holding up the 4 faces but the faces were gone so it looked like empty space. What i did was delete the 1 inner vertex and then proceeded to extrude both right side edges twice to make 4 newfaces then merging the newly created vertices with existing ones

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new vertexes and then using the fill hotkey F, I was able to resolve this by extruding 2 new edges and merging vertexes with existing ones. Then extrude 2 more edges and merge all vertexes and in this way I created 4 new faces that dont have any issues. Still dont know what caused it but this worked to solve it atleast.